# Kotlin list iterator jumps to last element

Tags: android, arrays, loops, android-studio, kotlin

I wrote in code comments primarily whats going on with the code but here is a little more indepth. I created an array of drawable resources (images). I created a button and assigned its function to switch to the next element of the array with a click. ( Once its at the last element I intend to have it go back to element[0] but I haven't gotten that far yet).

I'm pretty new to android development so I hope this isn't a silly question. when I run the app and click the button, it jumps to the very last element. I also noticed it does not even show the first element on the screen ( just blank, then on a button click you see last element). below is the picture of whats happening:

p.s. there used to be more array elements but I deleted them to see if they were the problem.

p.s.s
here is the actual code

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        //here I created an array of drawable images to pick from for the hair options
        val blankHairStyleList = arrayOf(R.drawable.hairponytailpink ,  R.drawable.hairponytailblue)

        //here I created an iterator which allows me to move through the array.
       val blankHairStyleListIterator = blankHairStyleList.iterator()

        //created button's click action
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.HairButton).setOnClickListener{

            //here is the actual iterator function, I feel like something is missing above here.
          while(blankHairStyleListIterator.hasNext()){
              findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleListIterator.next())
          }
        }
```

[photo of whats happeneing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XCpY.jpg)

Comment: Please paste the actual code here instead of putting an image.

Comment: Your list iterator does the exact same thing on each iteration, setting the image on the same button. So only the last iteration accomplishes anything lasting. Maybe you mean to make one iteration step on each click of the button? I would explain more, but don't want to have to retype your code to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great start! Here's how you can fix it up.

> I created a button and assigned its function to switch to the next element of the array with a click.

What you have right now will always cycle to the end because the `while` loop will keep running as long as `#hasNext` is true.

```kotlin
while (blankHairStyleListIterator.hasNext()) {
  findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleListIterator.next())
}
```

If you change the `while` to an `if`, the block will only run once!

```kotlin
if (blankHairStyleListIterator.hasNext()) {
  findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleListIterator.next())
}
```

> Once its at the last element I intend to have it go back to element[0] but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Once you have that if statement, you can use the else to create a new iterator (after you make the `blankHairStyleListIterator` a `var` instead of a `val`).

```kotlin
if (blankHairStyleListIterator.hasNext()) {
  findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleListIterator.next())
} else {
  findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleList.first())
  blankHairStyleListIterator = blankHairStyleList.iterator()
}
```

> I also noticed it does not even show the first element on the screen (just blank, then on a button click you see last element).

You need to set the element on the `ImageView`. You can put something like this before the `setOnClickListener`.

```kotlin
findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleList.first())
```

Please let me know if this does the trick for you!

Comment: This helped me so much, thank you so much. I really appreciate how thoughtfully you described everything! Thank You!!!!

Comment: Of course! Feel free to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You want something else as per your requirement and your code is doing a different thing.
As per your code, you are setting image background until your iterator has reached last item as below -

```
 findViewById<Button>(R.id.HairButton).setOnClickListener{
      while(blankHairStyleListIterator.hasNext()){
        findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleListIterator.next())
      }
    }
```

Because you are using while so code will set last item as background by skipping all of the previous items.

You need to make change in your code as per your requirement as below -

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.HairButton).setOnClickListener{
  if(blankHairStyleListIterator.hasNext()){
    findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.picture).setBackgroundResource(blankHairStyleListIterator.next())
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!